# Выполнение функции в случае выбора конкретного элемента в <section>

Tags: javascript

Есть такая форма. Необходимо, чтобы при выборе option со значением value=1 выполнялась моя функция. Как это реализовать?

```
  <form id="calc">
                    <select name = "choice">
                      <option value = "1">Вариант 1
                      <option value = "2">Вариант 2
                      <option value = "3">Вариант 3
                    </select></br>              
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myCoolFunc() {
  console.log('Hello World!');
}

document.querySelector('#calc select[name=choice]').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value === '1') {
    myCoolFunc();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<form id="calc">
  <select name="choice">
    <option>&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="1">Вариант 1</option>
    <option value="2">Вариант 2</option>
    <option value="3">Вариант 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Сделал так, что ф-ция присвает переменной значение `function doMyFunction(){
   ch=5;
   console.log('Hello World!');
  }` 
но она почему-то не работает. В чем проблема? Переменная определена

Comment: @jon4eg, что значит "*не работает*" и что именно не работает?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y70tw3jz/ при выборе value="1" в поле result должна вывестись переменная ch, которой я присвоил значение в своей функции.

Comment: поместите `document.getElementById('calc').result.value = ch;` внутри `doMyFunction`

Comment: я озадачен - человек знает, как создать работающий jsfiddle, но не понимает, что при вызове функции выполняется код, который внутри функции, а не снаружи.

Comment: @Igor, а разве функция не меняет переменную глобально?

Comment: @jon4eg - меняет, конечно. Но `document.getElementById('calc').result.value` и переменная `ch` - две не связанные вещи. Ваша строчка `...result.value = ch;` отнюдь не означает, что с этого момента любое изменение `ch` будет отражаться в значении `input`a. Она всего лишь присваивает значение переменной на данный момент (момент выполнения операции) значению `input`a. И все.

Comment: @Igor, а как тогда сделать, чтобы любое изменение `ch` отражалось в значении `input`?

Comment: @jon4eg Не заводить переменную `ch`, а завести функцию `function ch(value) { var el = document.getElementById('calc').result; if (arguments.length == 0) { return el.value; } else { el.value = value; } }` и вызывать ее без параметров, когда надо получить значение и с параметром - когда назначить.

Comment: @Igor, а подскажите, как работает эта ф-ция. Как я понял, сначала она берет значение поля `value` и заносит его в переменную `el`, затем проверяет  не пустое ли это значение и вот что дальше? Что значит `el.value`?

Comment: @jon4eg - смотрите ответ - это, конечно, не ответ на первоначальный вопрос, но приводить код в комментариях очень неудобно.

Answer (score 0):

Не заводить переменную `ch`, а завести функцию

```
function ch(value) { 
  var el = document.getElementById('calc').result; // get input element
  if (arguments.length == 0) { // check how the function was called
    return el.value; // if it was called cn() - return element value
  } else { 
    el.value = value; // if it was called cn(something) - set element value
  } 
}
```

и вызывать ее без параметров, когда надо получить значение:

```
// get current value from input 
var a = cn();
```

и с параметром - когда назначить:

```
// set input value
var b = 5;
cn(b);
```